# Implode() array and make new line after two elements

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, newline, implode

I am looking to echo comma separated elements of an array e.g:

`Element1, Element2, Element3, Element4, Element5, Element6`

However, for the purposes of keeping the echoed elements neat, I might need to go to a new line after the each second element of each line e.g

```
Element1, Element2,
Element3, Element4,
Element5, Element6
```

As is I am doing:

```
<?php
$labels = Requisitions::getLabelNames($id);
foreach($labels as $label) { 
    $labels_array[] = $label['name'];
    }  
echo implode(' ,', $labels_array); 
?>
```

And obviously getting:

`Element1, Element2, Element3, Element4, Element5, Element6`

How then do i do a newline after each second element of a line using `implode()` or otherwise?

Comment: keep a counter. and when `counter%2 == 0` add `\n`

Comment: Depending on what you want to do next, [`array_chunk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) might be helpful.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks, it returns `array`. Yet I want to display only the values of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use foreach to achive it, im pasting code for you which will give you your desired output

```
<?php
$labels = array("Element1", "Element2", "Element3", "Element4", "Element5","Element6");
$key = 1;
$lastkey = sizeof($labels);
foreach($labels as $value)
{
  if($key%2)
  {
    if($key==$lastkey)
    {
      echo $value;
    }
    else
    {
      echo $value.",</br>";
    }
  }
  else
  {
     if($key==$lastkey)
     {
        echo $value."</br>";
     }
     else
     {
        echo $value.",</br>";
     }
  }
  $key++;
}
?>
```

Comment: How do I now not have the comma after the last element of the last line using your solution?

Comment: just replace `else
  {
    echo $value.",</br>";
  }` with `else
  {
    echo $value."</br>";
  }`

Comment: @watkib i edited code. please check it, it will solve your printing comma problem

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$labels = array('Element1', 'Element2', 'Element3', 'Element4', 'Element5', 'Element6');

# Put them into pairs
$pairs_array = array_chunk($labels, 2);

# Use array_map with custom function
function joinTwoStrings($one_pair) {
  return $one_pair[0] . ', ' . $one_pair[1];
}

$pairs_array = array_map('joinTwoStrings', $pairs_array);

echo implode(',' . PHP_EOL, $pairs_array);
```

Comment: Thank you this does it too. Learnt something new too `PHP_EOL` interesting.

Answer (score 1):

untested, but something like this should work

```
$i = 1;

foreach($labels as $label) {
   echo $label;

   // add a comma if the label is not the last
   if($i < count($labels)) {
      echo ", ";
   }

   // $i%2 is 0 when $i is even
   if($i%2==0) {
       echo "<br>"; // or echo "\n";
   }    
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: I've read that for testing parity it's faster to use `$i && 1`

Comment: It would have to be & 1, not && 1. && being a boolean operator will always return true when both sides are positive numbers. & 1 will return 1 if, and only if, the lowest bit is set.

Comment: $i&1 Its a faster version of $i%2 but i dont know if it is necessary for your case. especially when you are a beginner its a little bit tricky to understand. If you like to know you can read more about here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php ("$i & 1" is 1 if $i is odd)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$labels = Requisitions::getLabelNames($id);
foreach($labels as $label) { 
    $labels_array[] = $label['name'];
    }

for($i=0;$i<count($labels_array);$i++)
{ echo($labels_array[$i]);
  if($i % 2 != 0)
  {
     echo("\n");
  }else{echo(",");}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of fancy:

```
$labels_array=array("Element 1","Element 2","Element 3","Element 4","Element 5","Element 6");
echo implode(",\n",array_map(function($i){ // change to ",<br />" for HTML output
    return implode(", ",$i);
},array_chunk($labels_array,2)));
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/Him17)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the array for something else, this just builds the string...

```
<?php
$labels = Requisitions::getLabelNames($id);
$s='';
$i=0;
$l=count($labels);
foreach($labels as $label){
    $s.=$label['name'];
    // Append delimeter. Makes sure every second, and the last one, will be a line break
    $s.=((++$i%2)&&($l!=$i))?' ,':"\n";  
}
echo $s;
?>
```

If you do need the array for something, create it first and modify above as needed.